# How can I return a success and an error promise with and without data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I would like to return a promise and an object called `output` either before or after the $http call. Can someone advise me how I can do this with the AngularJS framework and very important with **Typescript** so I can be sure it is working correctly?

```
 topicNewSubmit = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var myData1 = { abc: 123 }

    if (self.abc = 22) {
        // How can I return an OKAY promise from here?
    }
    if (self.abc = 33) {
        // How can I return an OKAY promise with myData1 from here?
    }
    if (self.abc = 88) {
        // How can I return a FAIL promise from here?
    }

    return self.$http({ url: self.url, method: "GET" })
        .then(
            (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {            
            var myData2 = { abc: 245 }
            // How can I return a promise and myData2. 
            // return(myData2) gives an error with Typescript

            // How can I return a promise and no data
            // return gives an error with Typescript 
        },
        (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): ng.IPromise<any> => {
            var myData3 = { abc: 345 }
            // Is this the correct way to return an unhandled reject with myData3
            return self.$q.reject(myData);
        });
  }
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve `$q` has a `resolve` method. If you are using an earlier version of Angular, use `.when`. They do the same thing. Also, `$http` methods return promises already. You shouldn't need to use another promise chain internally.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - If you have a few minutes could you please add your comments as an answer based on my short code example.  I'm not really sure what you mean by "$http methods return promises already. You shouldn't need to use another promise chain internally".  One thing I saw from my testing and the reason I added the self.$q.reject was that if I did handle the reject without the return there, then my topicNewSubmit would always return okay.  Hope this makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: I advise you get it working with normal javascript then port it to typescript, not that porting it to typescript is particularly hard... if you know typescript then it should be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Fixed the code and added a [TypeScript Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IHttpService%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(config%3A%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IPromise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20then%3CTResult%3E(successCallback%3A%20(promiseValue%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%7CTResult%7CIPromise%3Cvoid%3E%2C%20errorCallback%3F%3A%20(reason%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20notifyCallback%3F%3A%20(state%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20catch%3CTResult%3E(onRejected%3A%20(reason%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%7CTResult)%3A%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20finally(finallyCallback%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IDeferred%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(value%3F%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20reject(reason%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20notify(state%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20promise%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IQService%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%2C%20reject%3A%20IQResolveReject%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%2C%20reject%3A%20IQResolveReject%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all%3CT%3E(promises%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%5B%5D)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all(promises%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%20%7D)%3A%20IPromise%3C%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(promises%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%20%7D)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20defer%3CT%3E()%3A%20IDeferred%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20reject(reason%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20when%3CT%3E(value%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%7CT)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20when()%3A%20IPromise%3Cvoid%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%2F%20START%20EXAMPLE%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Definition%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FooService%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%24q%3A%20IQService%3B%0A%20%20%24http%3A%20IHttpService%3B%0A%20%20abc%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20url%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20topicTest%20%3D%20()%3A%20IPromise%3CFoo%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20return%20a%20promise%20which%20will%20result%20in%20a%20parameter%20of%20MyType%20upon%20resolving%0A%20%20%20%20var%20deferred%20%3D%20this.%24q.defer%3CFoo%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20the%20deferred%20to%20get%20better%20'intellisense'%20support%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.abc%20%3D%2099)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20deferred.resolve(%22Please%20put%20a%20type%20of%20Foo%20here%20%3A(%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.abc%20%3D%2088)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20deferred.reject(%22You%20can%20pass%20in%20whatever%20you%20like%20to%20the%20reject%20case%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20deferred.promise%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20topicNewSubmit%20%3D%20()%20%3A%20IPromise%3CFoo%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.%24http(%7B%20url%3A%20this.url%2C%20method%3A%20%22GET%22%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((response)%3A%20String%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20(error)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22whatever%20you'd%20like%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Usage%0Avar%20fooService%20%3D%20new%20FooService()%3B%0AfooService.topicTest().then(function(typeResultToTheCorrectTypeAKAFoo%3A%20number)%7B%7D)%3B%0AfooService.topicNewSubmit().then(function(data%3A%20string)%7B%7D)%3B). The methods are correctly typed, you can verify this by the typing errors that are thrown, try and fix them ;). I copied over the very basic required interfaces from the angular definition file.

**Edit #2**: [Here's the fixed version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IHttpService%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(config%3A%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IPromise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20then%3CTResult%3E(successCallback%3A%20(promiseValue%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%7CTResult%7CIPromise%3Cvoid%3E%2C%20errorCallback%3F%3A%20(reason%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20notifyCallback%3F%3A%20(state%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20catch%3CTResult%3E(onRejected%3A%20(reason%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%7CTResult)%3A%20IPromise%3CTResult%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20finally(finallyCallback%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IDeferred%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(value%3F%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20reject(reason%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20notify(state%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20promise%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20IQService%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%2C%20reject%3A%20IQResolveReject%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(resolver%3A%20(resolve%3A%20IQResolveReject%3CT%3E%2C%20reject%3A%20IQResolveReject%3Cany%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all%3CT%3E(promises%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%5B%5D)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all(promises%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%20%7D)%3A%20IPromise%3C%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(promises%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%20%7D)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20defer%3CT%3E()%3A%20IDeferred%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20reject(reason%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20IPromise%3Cany%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20when%3CT%3E(value%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%7CT)%3A%20IPromise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20when()%3A%20IPromise%3Cvoid%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%2F%20START%20EXAMPLE%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Definition%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FooService%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%24q%3A%20IQService%3B%0A%20%20%24http%3A%20IHttpService%3B%0A%20%20abc%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20url%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20topicTest%20%3D%20()%3A%20IPromise%3CFoo%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20return%20a%20promise%20which%20will%20result%20in%20a%20parameter%20of%20MyType%20upon%20resolving%0A%20%20%20%20var%20deferred%20%3D%20this.%24q.defer%3CFoo%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20the%20deferred%20to%20get%20better%20'intellisense'%20support%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.abc%20%3D%2099)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20deferred.resolve(%7B%0A%09%09%20%20bar%3A%20%22I'm%20a%20Foo!%22%0A%09%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.abc%20%3D%2088)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20deferred.reject(%22You%20can%20pass%20in%20whatever%20you%20like%20to%20the%20reject%20case%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20deferred.promise%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20topicNewSubmit%20%3D%20()%20%3A%20IPromise%3CFoo%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.%24http(%7B%20url%3A%20this.url%2C%20method%3A%20%22GET%22%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((response)%3A%20Foo%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%09%09%09bar%3A%20%22I'm%20a%20Foo%20as%20well!%22%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20(error)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22whatever%20you'd%20like%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Usage%0Avar%20fooService%20%3D%20new%20FooService()%3B%0AfooService.topicTest().then(function(data%3A%20Foo)%7B%7D)%3B%0AfooService.topicNewSubmit().then(function(data%3A%20Foo)%7B%7D)%3B) of the TypeScript Playground example above.

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to define a return type for the service method stating it returns *a promise whose result upon resolving will be a certain object*?

In that case you're almost there, I've split up your two example methods in separate blocks, as they require a different approach.

On a general note, I removed the scope copying (`self = this`) as you are using the fat arrow methods, which will automatically scope the method to the outer lexical scope. In short, there's no need to do the scope copy and in fact, in your example self doesn't always point to the service (as you're copying the scope inside of the method instead of outside of it).

Also, please note the definition of an Angular promise (truncated):

```
interface IDeferred<T> {
    resolve(value?: T): void;
    reject(reason?: any): void;
}
```

As such, typing an Angular Promise will only add a typing for the **resolve** case of the promise, not for the rejected case. Consequently, when calling your service, it will verify that the result in the success handler is of the type you have defined, but the type of the parameters in the error handler is of type `any`.

## topicTest

For this method to work you need to inject `$q` into your service and then use it to create your own `deferred`

```
topicTest = (): IPromise<Foo> => { // return a promise which will result in a parameter of MyType upon resolving
    var deferred = this.$q.defer<Foo>(); // Type the deferred to get better 'intellisense' support
    if (this.abc = 99) {
        deferred.resolve(new Foo());
    }
    if (this.abc = 88) {
        deferred.reject("You can pass in whatever you like to the reject case");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

## topicNewSubmit

The `$http` already returns promises, so you only need to hook into these by attaching a `then` callback and *returning* from that method to allow chaining other `then` callabacks to it.

In that case the return type of your service method would be `angular.IPromise<() => any>` where you can replace `any` with a type you'd like. The return type of the `then` method would have to correspond to whatever type you chose for the generic placeholder in the return type of the service method.

```
topicNewSubmit = () : IPromise<Foo> => {
    return this.$http({ url: this.url, method: "GET" }).then((response): Foo => {
        return new Foo();
    }, (error) => {
        return "whatever you'd like, it does not have to correspond to Foo";
    });
}
```

You could then use your service like

```
MyService.topicNewSubmit().then((data) => {
    // data needs to be of type T, where T is the type you defined in the generic placeholder of IPromise<T>
}, (error: any) => {
    // In the error case, the parameters are of type any
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In my IDE return output in the topicNewSubmit is showing as an error:  Type '{ abc: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IPromise<any>'. Also in your answer the comment "// likewise error would now equal {abc: 'just an example'}" would not be reached as you are handling the error in topicNewSubmit and so it would return a success.

Comment: I'm not sure about the return type, will verify this later. But the error isn't handled in the success callback, so that example will work. The `then` method accepts two callbacks a success and an error.

Comment: Hi Anne, my bad, I forgot to update the return type of the error callback, fixed this in my edit.

Comment: Hi, Just checked and if the error from the $http gets handled then it does not go to the "whatever you'd like" line. When I opened up the playground it showed quite a few syntax errors on my browser.

Comment: @Anne I know, that was to show you the typings were correctly working :). What do you mean, if the error gets handled?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the working code, I also included a link to the playground with the correct type usage (so there aren't syntax errors)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I feel like I'm shooting in the dark with your code sample, but here's my solution.

Like Anzeo, I removed the references to `self` or `this`. `$q` and `$http` should be assigned somewhere.

```
declare var $q: ng.IQService;
declare var $http: ng.IHttpService;

var topicNewSubmit = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {

    var deferred = $q.defer<any>();

    var myData1 = { abc: 123 };

    if (this.abc = 22) {

        deferred.resolve();

    } else if (this.abc = 33) {

        deferred.resolve(myData1);

    } else if (this.abc = 88) {

        deferred.reject();

    } else {

        $http({
            url: this.url,
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(() => {
            deferred.resolve({ abc: 245 });
        }, () => {
            deferred.reject({ abc: 345 });
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

You cannot return something that *isn't there yet* unless you *block all operations till you get it*. Since the browser JavaScript is (mostly) single threaded you *don't want to block the thread while the file downloads*. Hence you return a *promise* that will eventually resolve. The consumer needs to use the `then` function to *eventually* get the value.

## Humor

A promise is for life. Its s all the way down

Comment: My problem is that when I use: return self.$q.resolve(output);  it tells me that's not valid and $q. does not have a resolve.

Comment: `$q. does not have a resolve. ` sound like an *old* version of angular

Comment: So how can I return data from the success of a $http call? Also is return self.$q.reject('Error during Multi-save'); the correct way to return a failed promise from the fail block of a $http call?

Answer (score 2):

You can use promise like

```
var deferred = $q.deferred();
  $http(api url and method)
    .success function() {
         deferred.resolve(); 
    }
    .failure function()  {
        deferred.reject(); 
    }
    return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Don't agree, too. No need to return a promise from $http, as $http itself is a promise. See the angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http -> General Usage.